# Seasonal adjustment: Transfer of historical model to forecast values

Tags: time-series, forecasting, seasonality, seasonal-adjustment

I have a monthly time series provided by an external source, which contains both historical values and forecasts.

I'd like to seasonally adjust the time series using X-13ARIMA-SEATS in R (package "seasonal").

The data provider has recommended that I only use historical data as input. **My question is: How do I best go about transferring the results of the seasonal adjustment based on historical values to forecast values? Is this only possible if I (contrary to the advice given to me) include the forecast values right from the beginning?**

Comment: You may treat the sequence of forecast values as just another time series. You may then use your preferred method to seasonally adjust your time series. In short: you may set aside the advice given by the data provider. A problem *may* arise if the seasonal adjustment to the forecast series does not match exactly the adjustment to the historical series. It is not possible to know how much a problem that is, without knowing more about your application.

Comment: _"A problem may arise if the seasonal adjustment to the forecast series does not match exactly the adjustment to the historical series"_. If the seasonal adjustment of both series should ideally match, why can't I just seasonally adjust all of the series (historical + forecast) in one go to make sure that this is the case?